# Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

I've got at some code that should be recursively covering all positions on a boggle board. But for some reason it throws a segmentation fault after finding only 2 words? Any ideas why that would happen?

The code probably throwing the fault:

```
//++++++++++++ Find Word ++++++++++++++//
void findword(vector<vector<tile> > board, unsigned int row, unsigned int col, set<string> &results, unsigned int board_width, string word, set<string> dictionary)
{               
    if(checkbound(row, col, board_width) == false)          // If tile is outside of the boundary than do nothing
        return;
    if(board[row][col].getused() == true)               // If tile has already been used than do nothing
        return;
    word = word + board[row][col].getvalue();           // Adds letter to word

    //Check Prefixes
    set<string>::iterator pos;
    pos = dictionary.lower_bound(word);             // Creates an iterator at position
    if(pos== dictionary.end())                  // If it reaches the end without finding word than do nothing
    {
        return;

    }
    else if(word == pos->substr(0,word.length()))
    {
        cout<<"word: " <<word<<endl;
        cout<<"dict: " <<*pos<<endl;
        if(word == *pos)                    // If word = word at prefix
        {       
            cout<< word<<" word inserted"<<endl;    
            results.insert(word);               // Add words to results set
        }
    }
    else
        return;

    //set to used
    board[row][col].setused(true);                  // set tile to used




    findword(board, row-1, col-1, results, board_width, word, dictionary);  // Checks all tiles around every tile
    findword(board, row-1, col, results, board_width, word, dictionary);
    findword(board, row-1, col+1, results, board_width, word, dictionary);
    findword(board, row, col-1, results, board_width, word, dictionary);
    findword(board, row, col+1, results, board_width, word, dictionary);
    findword(board, row+1, col-1, results, board_width, word, dictionary);
    findword(board, row+1, col, results, board_width, word, dictionary);
    findword(board, row+1, col+1, results, board_width, word, dictionary);

    board[row][col].setused(false);                 // set tile to not-used
}
```

Error given:

```
word: r
dict: riot
word: ro
dict: robot
word: rob
dict: robot
word: robo
dict: robot
word: robot
dict: robot
robot word inserted
word: roo
dict: root
word: root
dict: root
root word inserted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Valgrind's main error code:

```
==4629== Invalid read of size 1
==4629==    at 0x407C2E: tile::getused() (tile.cpp:33)
==4629==    by 0x401ACE: findword(std::vector<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> >, std::allocator<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> > > >, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >&, unsigned int, std::string, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >) (main.cpp:58)
==4629==    by 0x4020EC: findword(std::vector<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> >, std::allocator<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> > > >, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >&, unsigned int, std::string, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >) (main.cpp:93)
==4629==    by 0x4020EC: findword(std::vector<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> >, std::allocator<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> > > >, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >&, unsigned int, std::string, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >) (main.cpp:93)
==4629==    by 0x401F78: findword(std::vector<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> >, std::allocator<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> > > >, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >&, unsigned int, std::string, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >) (main.cpp:91)
==4629==    by 0x402264: findword(std::vector<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> >, std::allocator<std::vector<tile, std::allocator<tile> > > >, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >&, unsigned int, std::string, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >) (main.cpp:95)
==4629==    by 0x402BF0: main (main.cpp:185)
==4629==  Address 0x4c3b178 is 8 bytes after a block of size 48 alloc'd
```

The Checkbound function:

```
//+++++++++++ Check Bounds ++++++++++++//
bool checkbound(unsigned int row, unsigned int col, unsigned int board_width)
{
    if(row < 0 || row > board_width || col < 0 || col > board_width)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

board:

```
r b o
o i t
r o h
```

Comment: Please don’t write `== true`.

Comment: What would you suggest instead @minitech

Comment: Give us a minimal complete example, and we'll crack this mystery like a rotten acorn.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the recursion the next word that should be found is riot... and the board is now shown above.

Comment: can you post your working code on ideone or somewhere, if it's not huge

Comment: @sukunrt Here's the link for all the code, I'm pretty new to programming so I'm not actually sure how to edit it into one file instead of 3. Thanks for your help! http://ideone.com/ToXiCF

Comment: You can use board.size() instead of pass variable board_width to findword function (and fix checkbound function as below). Also you pass board and dictionary by value (e.g. copy them every time when call findword() ), better way is pass them as const reference ( const vector< vector< tile > > &board, for example ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What value of board_width? If this is 3, then you forgot that indexing starting from 0 and maximum available index is 2, so condition in checkbound function must be:

```
    if(row < 0 || row >= board_width || col < 0 || col >= board_width)
```

Comment: this is the right answer, I think. This line in your board_width = sqrt(boardcnt.size()); might be giving this edge case error.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer!! Thanks so much, I feel ridiculous that I didn't catch that one.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your problem is in your checkbound function.  You do the following:

```
row > board_width
```

I'm not sure how you're counting the width, but I believe your problem is here.  A vector with  a size of 3 will be the indices:
myVec[0], myVec[1], myVec[2].

If in this example, you are saying the board_width is 3, this will cause your segfault.